# Push vertices outside of other object/setting ceiling to location of vertices

Tags: modifiers, vertices, displacement

I am looking for a way of creating a sort of Z ceiling for the position of my vertices, but cannot find anything by searching. I am most likely not knowledgeable enough to know what keywords to search for.

I have a plane with a wave modifier appended.

Above it I have another plane.

I want the waving plane's vertices to be capped/constrained by the above plane. So that if a waving vertex tries to go above the Z of the above plane, it will be capped and placed on the above plane's Z.

[image: Something like this]

Comment: You want to use the shrinkwrap modifier and constrain it to a postiive/negative axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can use a *"schrinkwrap modifier"*.

[image]

Using the following settings:

[image]

Projection, on the plane surface, along Z axis, for the Suzanne parts that become negative relative to it.